# Profile C++ code based on "State Threads" library with dtrace

Tags: c++, profiling, dtrace

I'm using `dtrace` to profile a C++ program (It's [SRS](https://github.com/winlinvip/srs/) in case it matters) based on [State Threads](https://sourceforge.net/projects/state-threads/), a goroutine-like library for writing concurrent C++ code.

The command I use:

```
dtrace -n 'profile-199 /pid == '$PID'/ { @[ustack(100)] = count(); } tick-15s { exit(0); }' -o $OUTPUT_FILE &>/dev/null
```

The sampling output and the flame graph shows the majority of CPU time is spent on "State Threads"'s `_st_kq_dispatch` function, and the corresponding call stack is like

```
_st_kq_dispatch
_st_idle_thread_start
_st_thread_main
st_thread_create
st_usleep
...
```

which is next to useless by not revealing anything about execution of user functions. However if profiled with macOS's builtin `/usr/bin/sample`, the result is as expected. So what's wrong with my `dtrace` usage here? What is special about "State Threads" that makes it cannot be profiled using `dtrace` like other normal programs? (BTW System Integrity Protection is enabled on my macOS, is it a problem?)